# How to pass a struct from C++ to C?

Tags: c++, c, arrays, cuda

Updated:
main.h

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}vec3;
const int sizeOfGrid = 20000;
vec3 *grid[sizeOfGrid];//assume initialized
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
extern "C" void cudaTranslate(vec3 *x);
void display()
{
    cudaTranslate(grid);
}
```

lineCuda.cu

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <cuda.h>
#include "main.h"

extern "C" void cudaTranslate(vec3 *x)
{

}
```

getting:
 
main.obj : error LNK2005: "struct vec3 * * grid" (?grid@@3PAPAUvec3@@A) already defined in lineCuda.obj

fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: What did you try, and how did it fail so far? I can't see any obvious problems with your current approach.

Comment: You should put the `struct` definition in a header and `#include` it from both the `.cpp` and `.cu` files.

Comment: @Jeremiah: Given the code posted, that would merely be 100% equivalent, and thus would not be a solution. I realise that you posted that as a comment rather than an answer, so you may already know that.

Comment: Wouldn't `vec3 *grid[2000]` be passed as a `vec3 **`? Is the problem that you need to do `cudaTranslate(grid[n]`)?

Comment: Jeremiah, that should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @Tomalak: I'm not sure the poster realized that they should have the `struct` definition included in both files; that was what I was pointing out.

Comment: Your declarations of the argument type of `cudaTranslate` don't match.  (One is `vec3*`, the other is just `vec3`.)

Comment: @Kristopher: I was posting that as a sanity check, in case the poster thought that was the complete code and wasn't just omitting the struct definition in the question.  I'm not sure that is the actual problem.

Comment: Sorry guys, I wrote a lot of code, and I didn't want to paste the entire thing. I've moved the struct declaration into main.h and I have lineCuda.cu and main.cpp include main.h in the code. Now the compiler is complaining that it's already been defined: fatal error LNK1169: one or more multiply defined symbols found

Comment: I have revised the code.

Comment: @Ninja: Which symbols is it complaining are multiply defined?

Comment: @Ninja: Try making `sizeOfGrid` `static`.  I do not remember if `int` constants are automatically (I think so).

Comment: @Jeremiah error LNK2005: "struct vec3 * * grid" (?grid@@3PAPAUvec3@@A) already defined in lineCuda.obj

Comment: figured it out. Thanks Jeremiah. Added static to grid.

Comment: @Ninja: You don't show that in your code.  The function definition should not be in the header file, just the prototype.

Comment: @Ninja: That won't do what you want; it means there will be a different `grid` variable in each source file.

Comment: i got it now. don't need the grid variable in the header since i'm passing it anyways.

Comment: This has **nothing to do with mixing languages**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move grid to main.cpp. Pass it to lineCuda.cu. Problem solved.

Updated:
main.h

```
typedef struct
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
}vec3;
const int sizeOfGrid = 20000;
```

main.cpp

```
#include "main.h"
vec3 *grid[sizeOfGrid];//assume initialized
extern "C" void cudaTranslate(vec3 *x);
void display()
{
    cudaTranslate(grid);
}
```

Comment: or use `extern` in the header file.

Answer (score 0):

You could make this a lot simpler by removing `extern "C"` everywhere and just use C++ bindings.

Having said that, you actually have a multiply defined symbol `grid` because you are including the file main.h in two translation units. Move the line `vec3 *grid[sizeOfGrid]` to main.cpp.